# SortedArrayUsingSelector unrecognized Selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, unrecognized-selector

i am new to ios and i am really stuck at finding solution for this...

```
    animals = @{@"B" : @[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"],
            @"C" : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
            @"D" : @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"],
            @"E" : @[@"Emu"],
            @"G" : @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"],
            @"H" : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"],
            @"K" : @[@"Koala"],
            @"L" : @[@"Lion", @"Llama"],
            @"M" : @[@"Manatus", @"Meerkat"],
            @"P" : @[@"Panda", @"Peacock", @"Pig", @"Platypus", @"Polar Bear"],
            @"R" : @[@"Rhinoceros"],
            @"S" : @[@"Seagull"],
            @"T" : @[@"Tasmania Devil"],
            @"W" : @[@"Whale", @"Whale Shark", @"Wombat"]};
    animalSectionTitles = [[animals allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

the code above doesn't error but when i trying to insert array into NSDictionary, it always shows unrecognized selecter. What should i do to solve this problem?

```
while (sqlite3_step(statement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
        Word *univer = [[Word alloc] init];
        univer.Id =[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)];
        univer.word=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)];
        //NSLog(@"%@",univer.word);
        NSString *first = [univer.word substringToIndex:1];
        NSLog(@"%@",first);
        if([first isEqualToString:@"A"] || [first isEqualToString:@"a"]){
            [_A addObject:univer.word];
        }
        else if([first isEqualToString:@"B"] || [first isEqualToString:@"b"]){
            [_B addObject:univer.word];
        }
        else if([first isEqualToString:@"C"] || [first isEqualToString:@"c"]){
            [_C addObject:univer.word];
        }
        else if([first isEqualToString:@"D"] || [first isEqualToString:@"d"]){
            [_D addObject:univer.word];
        }
        else if([first isEqualToString:@"E"] || [first isEqualToString:@"e"]){
            [_E addObject:univer.word];
        }
        else if([first isEqualToString:@"F"] || [first isEqualToString:@"f"]){
            [_F addObject:univer.word];
        }
        else if([first isEqualToString:@"G"] || [first isEqualToString:@"g"]){
            [_G addObject:univer.word];
        }
        else if([first isEqualToString:@"H"] || [first isEqualToString:@"h"]){
            [_H addObject:univer.word];
        }
    }
animals= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H, nil];
animalSectionTitles = [[animals allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
animals= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_A,_B,_C,_D,_E,_F,_G,_H, nil];
```

When you create a dictionary with `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` the list of items you supply have to be `objectA, keyA, objectB, keyB, objectC, keyC, nil`. Right now it looks like all you have is `objectA, objectB, objectC, nil`. Which looks like this if you write it out:

```
animals = @{@[@"Bear", @"Black Swan", @"Buffalo"] : @[@"Camel", @"Cockatoo"],
            @[@"Dog", @"Donkey"] : @[@"Emu"],
            @[@"Giraffe", @"Greater Rhea"] : @[@"Hippopotamus", @"Horse"]};
```

When you call `[[animals allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]` it's calling the `compare:` selector on all of the items in `[animals allKeys]` which are `NSArray`s which don't support the `compare:` method and thus the unrecognized selector error.

Not sure exactly what you want but try this:

```
animals= [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_A, @"A", _B, @"B", _C, @"C", nil];
```

Comment: Curious why the answer was marked as accepted and then unmarked (note, I didn't downvote your question). Are there issues with the answer?